# TCP socket used in a TLS Openssl connection becomes readable after Openssl call returned WANT_WRITE

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm trying to create a generic TLS over TCP socket in C++, using Openssl. The socket would be used in programs running a select loop and utilizing non-blocking I/O.

I'm concerned about the case where the underlying TCP socket becomes readable after the previous `SSL_get_error` call returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`. I can think of two situations where this may occur:

- The local application and remote application simultaneously decide to send large amounts of data. Both applications call `SSL_write` simultaneously and subsequent `SSL_get_error` calls on both applications return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`. The TCP packets sent from both applications cross on the wire. The local application's TCP socket is now readable after the previous `SSL_get_error` call returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`.
- As above, except the remote Openssl library decides to perform SSL re-negotiation in the `SSL_write` call, prior to writing any application data. This simply changes the meaning of the data received on the local application's TCP socket from encrypted application data to session re-negotiation data.

How should the local application handle this data? Should it:

- call `SSL_write` as it is currently mid-write?
- call `SSL_read` as would happen if the socket is idle?

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/IpCv2crhG0w

Comment: A better thread on non-blocking `SSL_write` http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/SSL-MODE-ACCEPT-MOVING-WRITE-BUFFER-td6421.html#none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ and SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE can be caused by (re)negotiations or full socket buffers and can not only occure within SSL_read and SSL_write but also SSL_connect and SSL_accept on non-blocking sockets. All you have to do is to wait for the wanted socket state (e.g. readable or writable) and then repeat the same operation. E.g. if you get an SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ from SSL_write you wait until the socket gets readable (with select, poll or similar) and then call SSL_write again. Same with SSL_read.

It might also be useful to use SSL_CTX_set_mode with SSL_MODE_ACCEPT_MOVING_WRITE_BUFFER|SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE .

Comment: Thanks. What should happen to the data received on the local application's TCP socket in the scenarios in my question?

Comment: SSL reads/writes the data in frames, e.g. the data of each SSL_write are packet together in at least one frame prefixed by the size (max 16k). 
If it cannot send the full frame within SSL_write because the socket buffer inside the kernel is full it will send as much data as possible, keep the rest buffered and return SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. 
If it returns the errors because it needs data to finish a handshake (e.g. (re)negotiation) it will not send any data before the handshake is finished.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. That explanation makes sense, however, it doesn't answer my question. What should the application do if it receives TCP data after `SSL_write`, for example, has returned `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`? See opening question for examples of when this scenario may occur.

Comment: If the socket is readable (and the SSL connection already established) you should call SSL_read, unless the last call of SSL_write returned SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. Only in the latter case you should retry SSL_write.

Comment: If I correctly understand what your saying, it's possible to call `SSL_read` while there is an outstanding, partially-complete write operation. For example, the following is valid: 1) Call `SSL_write`, which happens to partially-complete, returning `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, 2) Socket becomes readable, so call `SSL_read`, 3) Socket becomes writeable, so call `SSL_write`. Does the `SSL_read` call not interfere with the partially complete write operation?

Comment: Yes. You can do an SSL_read while having an incomplete SSL_write and you can also do an SSL_write while having an incomplete SSL_read.

Comment: Thanks for going through this. That answers my questions.